# Logistic regression interaction term p-value in python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, logistic-regression

I want to build a logistic regression and extract the p-value of the interaction term in Python where the dataset is imported from Teradata. But here comes some error message that I am not sure how to deal with.

I have tried two different ways to construct the logistic regression model. The first way cannot print out the model.summary() command therefore tried the second way. All of the variables include have converted to str and all of them are categorical variables.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from patsy import dmatrices;

y = testing.respond
feature_cols = ['t1', 't2', 'inter']
X = testing[feature_cols].as_matrix()

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
result = model.fit(X,y)
result.summary
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'summary'

model = sm.Logit(y, X)
model_fit = model.fit()
print(model_fit.summary)
ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).
```

Want to know how can I fix either of the model so that can get the result of the 'inter' term's p-value

Answer (score 0):

import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
try with smf.logit function then you will get p value & summary as well

Answer (score 0):

```
print(model_fit.summary())
```

You forgot the brackets on summary.